# Clear wathcman watches react-native

Tags: react-native

I have installed react native in windows 10 after deploying it in my android phone its gives me error

> unable to load scripts from assets 'index.android.bundle' on real device

After research I ran the following commands

```
react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res
```

It gives me 3 points

```
This might be related to https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4968
To resolve try the following:
  1. Clear watchman watches: `watchman watch-del-all`.
  2. Delete the `node_modules` folder: `rm -rf node_modules && npm install`.
  3. Reset Metro Bundler cache: `rm -rf /tmp/metro-bundler-cache-*` or `npm start -- --reset-cache`.  4. Remove haste cache: `rm -rf /tmp/haste-map-react-native-packager-*`.
```

How to resolve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a problem in version `0.56`

You will init `version 0.55` with this command

```
react-native init --version="0.55.0" AwesomeProject
```

Comment: I'm facing the same issue but I'm using expo-cli instead of react-native. How I can solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Go to your Project from Terminal or Cmd
Suppose My Project Name is React 
c:/React>
type cd android
c:/React/android>./gradlew cleanBuildCache
Click Enter and Refresh